# How do you download a folder from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Ideally I'd like to download a folder (not individual files) from Google Drive directly through a URL. Is it possible to download a folder from Google Drive? What URL or API do I use to do this?

Zipping the folder first with an url or api call then downloading would also be sufficient.

Comment: Is this a question about using the Drive API via a program you're writing, or a question about using drive.google.com?

Comment: Im asking if its possible to use the SDK or get a URL that doesn't expire.

Comment: It's not possible